# Navbar Button Doesn't Work in Production with Gatsby and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, gatsby, emotion

The stack for my project is GatsbyJS, TypeScript, Twin Macro (TailwindCSS), and Emotion.

In my ***styles.tsx*** file, I style and define my navbar button like this:

```sh
import React, {FC} from 'react'
import tw, {styled} from 'twin.macro'


export type ButtonComponentProps = {
    children?: any,
    onClick?: (e?: React.MouseEvent) => void
} & React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>

const ThisButton = ({onClick, children, ...rest}: ButtonComponentProps) => 
    <button onClick={onClick} {...rest}>{children}</button>

export const NavButton = tw(ThisButton)`
    text-black cursor-pointer text-xl leading-none px-3 py-1 border border-solid 
    border-transparent rounded bg-transparent block lg:hidden outline-none 
    focus:outline-none
`
```

Now my markup file, ***index.tsx*** looks like this:

```sh
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {faBars} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import {Nav, InnerNav, InnerMost, DropDown, Logo, NavButton,
    DropMenu, ListItem, InnerItem, ExtraButton
} from './styles'
import {StaticImage} from 'gatsby-plugin-image'


const Navbar = () => {
    const [navbarOpen, setNavbarOpen] = useState(false)

    return (
        <>
            <Nav>
                <InnerNav>
                    <InnerMost>
                        <Logo href="/">
                        <StaticImage 
                            src="../../images/logo.png"
                            alt="Company logo"
                            width={180}
                            placeholder="blurred"
                        />
                        </Logo>
                        <NavButton
                            type="button"
                            onClick={() => setNavbarOpen(!navbarOpen)}
                        >
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} />
                        </NavButton>
                    </InnerMost>
...
}

export default Navbar
```

What's so weird is that it works splendidly in development mode. But when I run `gatsby build` or deploy it, it doesn't work. Now if you're thinking the problem is FontAwesome, it's not. I replaced it, ran the build again and it still didn't work. I looked in my browser dev tools and everything looked fine until I saw the **Events Listeners** section. In development, all the event listeners you could think of, such as `click`, `close`, `load`, `mouseover`, etc. are there. However, in production, only `load` is there.

Can anyone help me, please!

Comment: Can you clarify or debug a little bit what's "doesn't work"? In addition, can you provide the gatsby-browser.js and the gatsby-ssr.js?

Comment: @FerranBuireu I'm only using gatsby-browser.js and I'm only importing fonts from the fontsource library. What doesn't work is that nothing happens when I click it. So considering only the `load` event is present in production but all the other event listeners are present in development, something went really awry here.

Comment: `gatsby build behaves differently, mainly because of the SSR to when something doesn't work in build environment doesn't mean that was working fine, just that under some specific circumstances, Can you provide a repo or a sandbox to test it? Try commenting some components to identify the offending one

Comment: Can't share it since it's a private repo. I did find that other buttons are the same way. So it seems the types for my buttons are wrong.

Comment: Nevermind @FerranBuireu, even though the button in my contact form only has the `load` event listener, it still works. Maybe because it's in a form? I don't know, but it does what it's supposed to do. So I'm perplexed right now why the navbar button won't work.